# Background process appears to hang

Tags: bash, shell, background-process, jobs, fifo

<sup>Editor's note: The OP is ultimately looking to package the code from [this answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/443297/write-to-stdin-of-a-running-process-us%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bing-pipe%20)
as a script. Said code creates a stay-open FIFO from which a background command reads data to process as it arrives.</sup>

It works if I type it in the terminal, but it won't work if I enter those commands in a script file and run it.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 cat >a&
 pid=$!
```

it seems that the program is stuck at `cat>a&`

`$pid` has no value after running the script, but the `cat` process seems to exist.

Comment: What are you trying to cat ? 'a' will be empty.

Comment: Of course `pid` won't have a value *after the script exits* -- all shell variables, by their nature, go away when the shell does. Script exits -> shell running the script exits -> no more variables.

Comment: @Prabhu I'm trying to write a script for the answer in the question. it only works if i type it in terminal line by line   http://serverfault.com/questions/443297/write-to-stdin-of-a-running-process-us%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bing-pipe%20–

Comment: Which version of bash is this? If what you really want is a coprocess (which, given the link, looks likely), modern (4.x) versions of bash have much less hacky ways of achieving that effect.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Assuming I'm correct about what the OP is trying to do (see my answer): I do not see a way to do it with a `coproc`, but I'm curious if you can think of one.

Comment: @mklement0, ...well, "what the OP is trying to do" is the critical issue here. If they really do need a FIFO, a coprocess is inappropriate. If they only *think* they need a FIFO... but, well, that's the issue; they haven't described their end goal in enough detail for us to know how what they're actually up to.

Answer (score 3):

**[cdarke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29621440/45375)** contains the **crucial pointer**: **your script mustn't run in a *child* process, so you have to *source* it**.

Based on the question you linked to, it sounds like you're trying to do the following:

- Open a FIFO (named pipe).
- Keep that FIFO open indefinitely.
- Make a *background* command read from that FIFO whenever new data is sent to it.

See bottom for a working solution.

As for an **explanation of your symptoms**:

- Running your script **NOT sourced** (NOT with `.`) means that the script **runs in a *child process***, which has the following implications:

  - **Variables defined in the script are only visible inside that script**, and the variables cease to exist altogether when the script finishes running.

    - That's why you didn't see the script's `$myPid` variable after running the script.
  - **When the script finishes running, its background tasks (`cat >a&`) are killed** (as cdarke explains, the `SIGHUP` signal is sent to them; any process that doesn't explicitly trap that signal is terminated).

    - This contradicts your claim that the `cat` process continues to exist, but my guess is that you mistook an *interactively* started `cat` process for one started by a *script*.
- By contrast, **any FIFO created by your script (with `mkfifo`) *does* persist** after the script exits (a FIFO behaves like a file - it persists until you explicitly delete it).

  - However, **when you *write* to that FIFO without another process *reading* from it, the writing command will *block* and thus *appear* to hang** (the *writing* process blocks until another process *reads* the data from the FIFO).

    - That's probably what happened in your case: because the script's background processes were killed, no one was reading from the FIFO, causing an attempt to write to it to block. You incorrectly surmised that it was the `cat >a&` command that was getting "stuck".

---

The following script, when sourced, adds functions to the current shell for **setting up and cleaning up a stay-open FIFO with a background command that processes data as it arrives**. Save it as file `bgfifo_funcs`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

[[ $0 != "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] || { echo "ERROR: This script must be SOURCED." >&2; exit 2; }

# Set up a background FIFO with a command listening for input.
# E.g.:
#    bgfifo_setup bgfifo "sed 's/^/@ /'"
#    echo 'hi' > bgfifo # -> '@ hi'
#    bgfifo_cleanup
bgfifo_setup() {

  (( $# == 2 )) || { echo "ERROR: usage: bgfifo_setup <fifo-file> <command>" >&2; return 2; }

  local fifoFile=$1 cmd=$2

  # Create the FIFO file.
  mkfifo "$fifoFile" || return

  # Use a dummy background command that keeps the FIFO *open*.
  # Without this, it would be closed after the first time you write to it.
  # NOTE: This call inevitably outputs a job control message that looks
  #       something like this:
  #         [1]+  Stopped                 cat > ...
  { cat > "$fifoFile" & } 2>/dev/null

  # Note: The keep-the-FIFO-open `cat` PID is the only one we need to save for
  #       later cleanup.
  #       The background processing command launched below will terminate
  #       automatically then FIFO is closed when the `cat` process is killed.
  __bgfifo_pid=$!

  # Now launch the actual background command that should read from the FIFO 
  # whenever data is sent.
  { eval "$cmd" < "$fifoFile" & } 2>/dev/null || return

  # Save the *full* path of the FIFO file in a global variable for reliable
  # cleanup later.
  __bgfifo_file=$fifoFile
  [[ $__bgfifo_file == /* ]] || __bgfifo_file="$PWD/$__bgfifo_file"

  echo "FIFO '$fifoFile' set up, awaiting input for: $cmd"
  echo "(Ignore the '[1]+  Stopped ...' message below.)"
}

# Cleanup function that you must call when done, to remove
# the FIFO file and kill the background commands.
bgfifo_cleanup() {
  [[ -n $__bgfifo_file ]] || { echo "(Nothing to clean up.)"; return 0; }
  echo "Removing FIFO '$__bgfifo_file' and terminating associated background processes..."
  rm "$__bgfifo_file"
  kill $__bgfifo_pid  # Note: We let the job control messages display.
  unset __bgfifo_file __bgfifo_pid
  return 0
}
```

Then, *source* script `bgfifo_funcs`, using the `.` shell builtin:

```
. bgfifo_funcs
```

**Sourcing executes the script in the *current* shell** (rather than in a child process that terminates after the script has run), and thus makes the script's functions and variables available to the current shell. **Functions by definition run in the current shell, so any background commands started from functions stay alive**.

Now you can set up a stay-open FIFO with a background process that processes input as it arrives as follows:

```
# Set up FIFO 'bgfifo in the current dir. and process lines sent to it
# with a sample Sed command that simply prepends '@ ' to every line.
$ bgfifo_setup bgfifo "sed 's/^/@ /'"

# Send sample data to the FIFO.
$ echo 'Hi.' > bgfifo
@ Hi.

# ...

$ echo 'Hi again.' > bgfifo
@ Hi again.

# ...

# Clean up when done.
$ bgfifo_cleanup
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason that `cat >a` "hangs" is because it is reading from the standard input stream (stdin, file descriptor zero), which defaults to the keyboard.

Adding the `&` causes it to run in background, which disconnects from the keyboard.  Normally that would leave a suspended job in background, but, since you exit your script, its background tasks are killed (sends a SIGHUP signal).

EDIT:  although I followed the link in the question, it was not stated originally that the OP was actually using a FIFO at that stage.  So thanks to @mklement0.

I don't understand what you are trying to do here, but I suspect you need to run it as a "sourced" file, as follows:

```
. gash.sh
```

Where `gash.sh` is the name of your script.  Note the preceding `.`

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head with respect to the need to *source* the script.
However, I suspect the "hanging" doesn't come from the `cat` command (which the OP states is executed with `&` even interactively), but from a subsequent attempt to write to _FIFO_ `a`, at whose other end no one is listening anymore, due to the script having exited (I filled in the missing pieces from the linked serverfault.com question).

Comment: @mklement0: absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a file with "cat":

```
 #!/bin/bash
 cat SOMEFILE >a &
 pid=$!
 echo PID $pid
```

Although that seems a bit silly - why not just "cp" the file (`cp SOMEFILE a`)?

Q: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The advantage is that you can concat multiple files with `cat`, but not with `cp`. Just saying.

Comment: Oh one other thing you can't do with `cp`: you can `cat` character devices, e.g., `/dev/null`. (Just stating the obvious.)

Comment: Following the OP's link -- `a` is a FIFO, which makes the reason for not using `cp` clear.